# Using a singular to mean a plural

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Suppose I have a sentence of the form:

> Ahead I see a red door and a blue door - the path to each is similar.

Is this grammatically correct? It sounds odd if I pluralise "path", but this version doesn't seem to make sense either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is grammatically correct; in fact, pluralizing *paths* makes it incorrect.

Because the word *each* is singular, *path* should likewise be singular.  If that is at all confusing, let me explain further:  Though *each* is often notionally plural, which is to say that it evokes an image of more than one entity, it is grammatically singular.  This is because it refers to each entity individually.  As you read in that previous sentence, I said *each entity* and not **each entities*.

Comment: Whether or not 'the path to each is similar' or 'the paths to each are similar' is the correct choice depends on how many paths approach each door.

Comment: But one thing can't be similar ... it takes two things to be similar. So it really should be *are*.